# Which folder\entity in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps corresponds to a given Modern UI app URI?

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts, modern-ui, uri, windows-8-apps

Problem fully described (with screenshots and links, which are limited for new SU accounts) here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_store/broken-modern-app-shortcuts-in-windows-81-after/994b978b-f199-4db2-910f-b5b914acd797

Basically updating from Windows 8 Pro with Media Center x64 to 8.1 Pro with Media Center x64 produces a few dead modern app URIs in my All Apps listing that I can't remove or fix (screenshots and details in preceding link). This has happened on 2 separate machines attached to the same Microsoft Account.

Help? Ideas?

**UPDATE**

I found the problem (see below) and now just need to delete the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps entries/shortcuts that match the broken Modern UI app URIs. The problematic URIs are:

```
ms-resource:///photo/residAppName
ms-resource:app_name
ms-resource:chatAppTitle
ms-resource:manifestDisplayName
ms-resource:ShortProductName
```

Anyone know which C:\Program Files\WindowsApps entries the above correspond to?

Comment: Have you uninstalled then reinstalled those applications?  This unlikely won't get rid of the icons but will fix at least fix the apps

Comment: I can't uninstall them because there's no option to do so. See the OP I linked to above.

Comment: @rch - I am not sure the reason I said try to uninstall them, clearly your unable to do that, but have you tried to reinstall the application?  Its really good to have all the information in a single location, so when that forum thread doesn't exist tommorow, the question is complete.  Don't worry about inline screenshots people can do that for you just provide a link to the screenshot in the post.

Comment: @Ramhound: I would put all the info in a single location if SU didn't prevent new users from posting images or more than a single link. Completely ridiculous limitation that prevents people with serious problems from being to explain themselves fully *gets off soapbox* This particular problem is VERY difficult to explain without screenshots.

Comment: @Ramhound: Good idea about reinstalling, but the URIs appear to correspond to stock Win 8.1 apps such as Photos, Camera, and Chat (now deprecated and replaced by Skype) that can't be uninstalled anyway. Try right clicking on your Win 8.1 Camera app, you'll find there's no Uninstall option available.

Comment: I don't have any of those 3 applications installed.  They are no longer in the Windows 8.1 Windows Store.  This means manual removal should be possible.  Which you already tried to access.  Honestly I didn't have the problem, which means, there is something installed on your system that caused it.  Which I know isn't helpful to hear I suppose.  I mean taking ownership of the required folder is a bad idea, but might be required, a new profile honestly might be in order.  You say you believe it would take awhile, its a couple steps, and all your applications would be downloaded again.

Comment: Do you have ANY Windows 8 computers connected to this same Microsoft Account by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound: Nope, they're all Windows 8.1 machines and were all updated simultaneously. From further discussion with other people with the problem (see OP link), it seems the common thread/possible source is Avast 2014 running at the time of the 8.1 update.

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited the original question to ask which C:\Program Files\WindowsApps entries to delete to remove the broken shortcuts